# Applying a function to every column of a data frame

Tags: r

I need to transform data in a multiple-column dataframe and would like to find a way to do the transformation in all columns of the dataframe at once. A data transformation of numerical data seems unproblematic. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  co1 = c(5,9,6,1,6),
  co2 = c(8,5,4,6,2), 
  co3 = c(6,5,4,1,2),
  co4 = c(6,1,5,3,2),
  co5 = c(5,1,2,6,8))
```

I can either use a for loop to transform all data at once (e.g., mark all values > 5 as "yes", all others as "no"):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[i] <- ifelse(df[i] > 5, "yes", "no")
}
```

or, more simply, use indices:

```
df[] <- ifelse(df > 5, "yes", "no")
```

However, when I have character data, these methods don't work. For example, I want to transform into "yes" all values starting with "A" in this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  co1 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co2 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")), 
  co3 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co4 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co5 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")))
df
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  JF  GB  ID  EB  DF
2  IA  DD  DA  IF  HD
3  HI  IH  JE  CH  FB
4  GE  JI  CJ  BA  GE
5  BG  EE  GG  AJ  BH
```

The for loop

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[i] <- ifelse(grepl("^B", df[i]), "yes", "no")
}
```

as well as the transfomation via indices produce the same incorrect transformation:

```
df[] <- ifelse(grepl("^B", df), "yes", "no")
df
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  no  no  no  no  no
2  no  no  no  no  no
3  no  no  no  no  no
4  no  no  no  no  no
5  no  no  no  no  no
```

Any help how to achieve correct transformations with character data?

Comment: `ifelse` with `lapply/sapply/mutate_all` might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to stick to base R, `lapply` would work here:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  co1 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co2 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")), 
  co3 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co4 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co5 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")))

df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("^B", x), "yes", "no")))

  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  CA  JI  IH  JE  BB
2  HE  EC  GE  IG  DC
3  DH  FA  FI  FB  ID
4  GD  IJ  JC  HC  CJ
5  FC  AF  DA  AH  AF

  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  no  no  no  no yes
2  no  no  no  no  no
3  no  no  no  no  no
4  no  no  no  no  no
5  no  no  no  no  no
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`, we can do:

```
 df %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(grepl("^B",x),"Yes","No"))
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1 Yes  No Yes  No  No
2  No  No  No  No  No
3  No  No  No  No  No
4  No  No  No  No  No
5  No  No  No  No Yes
```

On data in the post(df1):

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(grepl("^B",x),"Yes","No"))
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  No  No  No  No  No
2  No  No  No  No  No
3  No  No  No  No  No
4  No  No  No Yes  No
5 Yes  No  No  No Yes
```

Data:

```
df
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  BH  IC  BC  HJ  CC
2  CC  DH  CF  GI  HI
3  DB  GE  JI  DA  GD
4  II  CA  EJ  IG  FA
5  JD  JB  IG  EB  BE
```

Comment: I've been trying to use dplyr before; but I get this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing what code your ran. I'm using the latest dplyr version.

Comment: I've updated the package today and run the same code you did

Comment: What is your dplyr version and what other packages are loaded? I'm using `dplyr` 0.8.2, only package I have in my session.

Comment: I've uninstalled dplyr and re-installed it just now but get this error: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'pkgconfig' 2.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: Upgrade R if possible, reinstall dplyr with dependencies set to T. Restart R.

Answer (score 3):

We could `unlist` the data and then use `grepl` directly in base R with indexing

```
df[] <- c("No", "Yes")[grepl("^B", unlist(df)) + 1]

df
#  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
#1  No  No  No  No  No
#2  No Yes  No  No  No
#3  No  No  No Yes  No
#4  No  No  No  No  No
#5  No  No  No  No Yes
```

**data**

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(
  co1 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co2 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")), 
  co3 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co4 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")),
  co5 = c(paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sample(LETTERS[1:10],5), sep = "")))

df
#  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
#1  HB  AE  ED  HD  HD
#2  JC  BD  CG  AH  DA
#3  GE  FI  HE  BI  JI
#4  IF  JB  JB  EE  FH
#5  CG  CF  DC  CA  BJ
```

Answer (score 2):

An option in `base R` with `substr`

```
out <- array("No", dim = dim(df), dimnames = dimnames(df))
out[substr(as.matrix(df), 1, 1) == "B"] <- "Yes"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(co1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("BF", 
"CH", "EC", "HB", "JJ"), class = "factor"), co2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("AD", "FI", "GA", "HH", "JB"), class = "factor"), 
    co3 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CJ", "DB", 
    "EF", "FH", "IG"), class = "factor"), co4 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("AE", "DH", "HA", "IF", "JC"), class = "factor"), 
    co5 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("AC", "BG", 
    "EE", "GI", "JJ"), class = "factor")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```